# I'm getting an error "ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key" if domain contains non ASCI character as "ö". What should I do?

Tags: non-ascii-characters, domain-name

I'm getting an error "ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key" if domain contains non ASCI character as "ö". What should I do?

I have a website with three domain names:

ksvermoegensverwaltung.ch

ksvv.ch

ksvermögensverwaltung.ch

Everything works for the first two, but I get the error message for the last one!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this but you may need to convert the domain name using `Punycode`. There are many `Punycode` converters on-line. If you convert the domain name

```
ksvermögensverwaltung.ch
```

to `Punycode` you will get

```
xn--ksvermgensverwaltung-89b.ch
```